# object literals inside constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, literals

I'm defining a simple shorthand function for element creation in JavaScript. Currently, I have:

```
 //simple creation function
function make(tag, style, id) {
    var obj = document.createElement(tag);
    if (style !== '' ) {
        obj.style.cssText = style;
    }
    if (id !== undefined) {
        obj.setAttribute('id',id);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And you call it simply enough:

```
var myDiv = make('div','float:right','myDiv');
```

But what I'd really like to do is define a function with a few more optional properties, similar to jQuery's creation function, e.g.:

```
var $myDiv = $('<div>', {id: 'myDiv', style: 'float:right'});
```

How could I set an object literal as one of the parameters of `make()` and call its values in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript places no restrictions on how you set up your function parameters. Simply call the object literal whatever you want in your parameter list and pass it in.

```
function make(tag, config) {
    var obj = document.createElement(tag);
    if (config.style !== '') {
        obj.style.cssText = config.style;
    }
    if (config.id) {
        obj.setAttribute('id', config.id);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

and call it like:

```
var myDiv = make('div', {style: 'float:right', id: 'myDiv'});
```

Comment: Easiest example in the world. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
function initializeObjectWithProperties(options){
    var newObject = {id:options.id};
    newObject.prop = options.prop;
    newObject.prop1 = options.prop1;
    newObject.style = options.style;
    return newObject;
}
initializeObjectWithProperties({id:0,prop:1,prop1:2,style:"MYSTYLE"})//returns newObject with all the properties and their corresponding values.
```

or unsafely

```
function initializeObjectWithProperties(options){
    var newObject = {}; //this could be an HTML object as well.
    for (var i in options){
        if (newObject[i] == undefined){
            newObject[i] = options[i]; //
        }
    }
    return newObject;//returns new object with all of option's properties
}
initializeObjectWithProperties({id:0,prop:1,prop2:2,anyRandomProp:"myRandomPropertyValue"});
```

although this method is unsafe because it also loops through the `Object` prototype, this one loops through all the properties of the object. You can use both these methods to add properties to another object. Javascript's objects can store almost everything.